# Event listener for externally loaded page

Tags: javascript

I have included an external page using an iframe. The page is a form and will accept input. I want to capture the successful submission of the form.

I notice that when the form was successfully submitted a div element is appended to the page (refer below):

```
 "<div class="appriseOverlay" id="aOverlay" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;"></div> <div class="appriseOuter" style="left: 50%; top: 200px; display: block; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"><div class="appriseInner">Data successfully submitted<div class="aButtons"><button value="ok">Ok</button></div></div></div>"
```

using the load seems not able to detect. I have no control over the external page.

Thank you all in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. The Same Origin Policy prevents you from accessing that.

The only access JavaScript has to cross-origin frames is via `postMessage` and friends. They require the cooperation of the external page.